# Toggle relative paths to cloud depending upon environment Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudfront

In trying to speed up my Node site, I've set up Amazon's CloudFront CDN to cache all static files on my server. I've configured a subdomain alias so instead of writing src="/mysite.css", I can write src="https://cache.mysite.com/mysite.css", and it will fetch the css file from the cloud, instead of my server.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I don't want to hard code all of my static files to direct to the cloud, because it will be very hard to further develop and test my site in the future. If I make a change locally to a css file, for example, and try to test it locally, the link to the css file will be directed to the cloud, not the local copy.

So I was trying to think of a way to rewrite the urls, conditionally on the environment. Is there a way to use the ENV file to set a variable, which will then be used to insert the cache url in front of all relative urls, or otherwise leave it blank so the link remains relative?

Comment: Run the whole site through CloudFront and you can just use all relative paths.

Comment: I initially thought I could do that, but Node won't run on CloudFront. CloudFront will only deliver static files like JS, images, CSS, etc.

Comment: That's not correct.  Any site, static or dynamic, can be placed behind CloudFront.  You use path patterns to tell CloudFront which paths go to your static storage (e.g. S3) and which paths go to your app server (it still runs the Node code for the site).  My sites have path patterns like `*.css` and `*.png` that go to static, and then the default pattern `*` goes to the application, and forwards cookies and query strings.  You can have up to 25 destinations ("cache behaviors" with "path patterns") all going to potentially different places on the back end ("origins"), by default.

Answer (score 0):

There's `process.env`[[documentation]](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) to get environment variable which you can then use in your code/templates.

You can also use modules like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)